# Add scrape_configs to Prometheus using Helm

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to add an extra scrape config to my prometheus configuration. For the installation I use Helm Charts. So, what I did, I created a `values.yaml` file with

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - localhost:9090
  - job_name: myapp
    static_configs: 
      - targets: ["myapp-service:3000"]
```

And then I executed the following command

```
$> helm install -f ./values.yaml stable/prometheus
```

This will spin up prometheus which I can access. But when I check the configuration or the `Targets` there is nothing about `myapp`.

I get the feeling that I forget something here or incorrectly add targets to the prometheus chart. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which section did you add the scrape jobs to? There should be a prometheus.yml section within the Helm chart which you can paste your jobs into, though do make sure you indent them correctly since it's a deeper indentation than in a kubernetes deployment file. I wrote [a short blog post](https://www.promlts.com/resources/wheres-my-prometheus-yml?utm_source=sof&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=prometheus) on finding/updating your prometheus.yml file in different settings which includes a Helm section; the article is about remote storage, but it should be the same process for adding scrape jobs.

Comment: I think you're right. I just added `serverFiles:` as a parent of `prometheus.yml` and it works. Thnx!

Answer (score 10):

You can add extra scraping settings with the `extraScrapeConfigs` directive.

```
# adds additional scrape configs to prometheus.yml
# must be a string so you have to add a | after extraScrapeConfigs:
# example adds prometheus-blackbox-exporter scrape config

extraScrapeConfigs: |
   - job_name: 'prometheus-blackbox-exporter'
     metrics_path: /probe
     params:
       module: [http_2xx]
     static_configs:
       - targets:
         - https://example.com
     relabel_configs:
       - source_labels: [__address__]
         target_label: __param_target
       - source_labels: [__param_target]
         target_label: instance
       - target_label: __address__
         replacement: prometheus-blackbox-exporter:9115
```

Check well the indentation while adding this to your `values.yml` . It must be a child of root.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to expand on @ale-tri's answer to say depending on the chart you used during the helm installation of Prometheus.
The values you should provide might differ.

If you used the `prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack` the `job_name` has to go under `prometheus.prometheusSpec.additionalScrapeConfigs`.

Check https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml for more information on the values you can override.

Example for anyone using `kube-prometheus-stack`

```yaml
prometheus:
  enabled: true
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs: |
      - job_name: prometheus
        static_configs:
          - targets:
            - localhost:9090
      - job_name: myapp
        static_configs: 
          - targets: ["myapp-service:3000"]
```

Comment: I added an example to illustrate your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with prometheus-operator v0.65.0, one can use the `ScrapeConfig` CRD to scrape targets external to the
Kubernetes cluster or create scrape configurations that are not possible with the higher level `ServiceMonitor`/`Probe`/`PodMonitor`.
This feature is currently added to prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack helm chart

[Chart github URL](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack)

Just add a scrapeconfig resource (it is much similar to lagacy prometheus configuration) and see it on prometheus dashboard

[Some document about ScrapeConfig](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/pull/5659/files/309cf7162b0c504d4ad5b7588126e072436ff208#diff-70602f39063a4df50b8fed0f013dae42a5ff86911f3b5a6a0fcd2f6cbdd10742)